# what do I call Adding Task Box?

Tags: task-list

[image: ADD TASK IMAGE]

What should I call this Adding Task box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an input field.

"Supply a name for your new tasks list in the Name: input field after clicking on the Tasks app".